# How can listen accesses to Windows APIs by processes

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I want to make a simple program in `.Net` that it watches the accesses to the `Win API` functions (like `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` for file system) and it let me know which proccess has access to which API.

Is there any interrupt approach or per-build component in `.Net Framework` to do this?

Comment: I'd recommend Detours from Alex's link. I've used it before to hook clipboard events in external processes.

Comment: Using .NET sure seems like the hard way to do this.